# How can I check if share certificates I found have value?

Tags: share-certificate

I have been clearing my parents flat and found share certificates from

- P and O
- European Ferries

Can I find out if they are still valid? If not, is there a market for them as collectibles or the like?

Comment: Check if the shares are still being traded on the exchanges.

Comment: I tidied up a little, it would help if you edited the company names to be precisely what they are on the certificates, and provided some location information (where your parents were living when they bought these) if you don't know the exchange they were bought on.

Comment: @DumbCoder I think if OP had any idea how to do that the question would not be asked here.

Comment: European Ferries: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Ferries; P & O is the successor (so now same company). After nearly 200 people died in a dumb accident (car door left open...), they renamed again to _Townsend-Thoresen_

Comment: P & O _purchased_ Townsend-Thoresen in 1987. Because of the ferry disaster (not a car door, but the bow door of the ferry) they rebranded the Townsend-Thoresen ship to P & O as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 7):

Both of these holdings are worth money.

[European Ferries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Ferries) was bought by P&O in 1987.

[P&O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%26O_(company)) was bought by [DP World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DP_World) in 2006.

You should be entitled to receive the price (or shares) paid for both holdings at the time of purchase, and possibly any subsequent dividends paid.  DP World paid 520p per share to purchase P&O, however I can not find any record of the deal P&O made to purchase European Ferries.

The place to start is by contacting DP World and explaining your situation.  Here is the [contact information for DP World](http://web.dpworld.com/contact/).  They are headquartered in Dubai, so this may be a slow process.

If you are unable to obtain a satisfactory conclusion, then I would contact the UK regulators - the [FSA = UK Financial Regulator](http://www.fsa.gov.uk/).

Comment: Thanks for that. Why is life so complicated!! This is all a mystery to me!!