# European Ferries Group PLC

Tags: shares

I have a Europeon Ferries group certificate which was my Fathers shares This changed to P&O i believe .I have the original with the certificate no How do i find out if they have been cashed in please. Dated 1987

Comment: Looks like a company called Compushare is the registrar for P&O shares: they'd probably be the place to start. See [Compushare - P&O Ferries Limited](https://www-uk.computershare.com/Investor/company/CoyContacts.asp?bhjs=1&amp;fla=0&IssuerId=SCUKPOF&cc=UK)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if share certificates I found have value?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/69533/how-can-i-check-if-share-certificates-i-found-have-value)